# How to use replaceAll() correct

Tags: android, textview, replaceall

I have a hangman-app which I fetch a random word from  Db i created, then I save it to `randomedWord` and then i make another String for holding `randomedWord` but replaced with only "_". This `hiddenWord` is displayed so the user knows how many chars there is.

When a user hits Enter a `onlicklistener` fires `guess()` method:

I have following code which initates a local String which has the value of a `TextView(userInput)`. Then if `randomedWord` contains the guess I want to put in guess into the same position as it is in the `randomedWord`, but now to `hiddenWord` and then update the `TextView` again.

Guess method:

```
public void guess() 
{
    String guess = userInput.getText().toString();

    if(randomedWord.contains(guess)) 
    {
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(guess, guess);
        this.wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
    } else 
    {
        showImages();
    }
}
```

The problem I think is this line:

```
hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(guess, guess);
```

because `hiddenWord` just contains "_" and therefore I can't replace with (guess, guess) where the first is WHAT to be replaced and last is WITHWHAT.

How do I replace the same POSITION as it is in `randomedWord` with guess into `hiddenWord`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it all solved! The feeling when everything works smoothly.... :)

Heres the code:

// Set listener to enter-button and do guess when textfield is not empty and toast that input need if it is

```
 enterLetterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (!(userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()) )
                {
                    guess();
                } else if (userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to insert a letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

// invWord() method. Converts the randomedWord to a string of "_".

```
public void invWord() 
    {
        hiddenWord = randomedWord;
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(".", "_" +" ");
    }
```

//guess() method. Puts the guess(char) at the index fetched and if the hiddenWord contains no more "_" winner() is called

```
  public void guess() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
        {
            char guess = userInput.getText().charAt(0);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
            String j = ""+guess;
            int index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess);

            if (randomedWord.contains(j))
            {
                while (index >= 0) 
                {
                    builder.setCharAt(index*2, guess);
                    index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
                    hiddenWord = builder.toString().trim();
                    wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
                    if (!(hiddenWord.toString().contains("_".toString())) )
                    {
                        winner();
                    }
                }   
            }
            else 
            {
                showImages();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your approach slightly.  When a user inputs and `guess()` is called, find all occurences of that guess in `randomedWord` and then set the characters in `hiddenWord` to guess.  Using `StringBuilder` and `String.indexOf()`, it would look something like this.  Also, guess will need to be a `char`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
int index = word.indexOf(guess);
while (index >= 0) {
    builder.setCharAt(index, guess);
    index = word.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
}
hiddenWord = builder.toString();
```

Comment: One problem though, when I use indexOf do i get all occurences? I mean in banana would i get [1,3,5] as index? and then u might think that setCharAT(index, guess) would fill all those indexes, but it doesnt, it just fills the first occurence. So if i have a word with more of the same letter it doesnt work properly. Do you have any input on this too?

Comment: Yes.  the method definition looks like `indexOf(int index, char guess)`.  The index of the first occurence after `index` of the character `guess` is returned.  So when we change the value of index, it iterates along the string to find each occurence.  I test it and it worked with multiple occurences of a character (see http://ideone.com/TeqsH ).

Comment: You're right, it wsnt working for me cause i tried to use a if statement while you uses a while, silly me. Then all occurences shows but instead showImages() is called every enter nd user gets "wrong". Look at the paste so you understand. How can I code do that in another way? I would like to just paste the else { showImages(); } to after the while-loop but I cant use else there... http://ideone.com/FKPs3

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem looks like this:

// INVWORD METHOD WHICH TURNS THE FETCHED WORD INTO A COPY BUT ONLY "_"

```
 public void invWord() 
    {
        hiddenWord = randomedWord;
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(".", "_");
    }
```

// GUESS METHOD WHICH IS CALLED WHEN ENTER-BUTTON ISCLICKED

```
 public void guess() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        char guess = userInput.getText().charAt(0);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
        String j = ""+guess;
        int index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess);

        if (randomedWord.contains(j))
        {
            while (index >= 0) 
            {
                builder.setCharAt(index, guess);
                index = randomedWord.indexOf(guess, index + 1);
                hiddenWord = builder.toString().trim();
                wordHolder.setText(hiddenWord);
                if (hiddenWord.trim().contains(randomedWord))
                {
                    winner();
                }
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            showImages();
        }
    }
```

Problem is that I would need to add a +" " to the hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replaceAll(".", "_"); to make the word be like _ _ _ _ _ and makes the user see how many ketters the word is. In my solution it will only be  long ***_*___**, but it works. If I set index*2 at builder.setCharAt(index, guess); the formatting will be good but then winner(); is never run, I guess because the " " makes the hiddenWord no longer = ranomedWord.

How can I solve this?